# CSS input.submit overruled in mobile

Tags: html, css

I have the following CSS for my input.sumbit which works perfectly.

```
//css
input.digipas {
  width: 176px;
  height: 48px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: #ef4969;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  line-height: 1.71;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: none;
  border: none;
}

//html
<input type="submit" class="digipas" name="submit" value="Valider">
```

It shows on my website like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzQZW.jpg 
Unfortunately, on mobile, the css becomes overruled by some strange force I don't know: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQgOV.jpg 
How can I fix this?!

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and _the shortest code necessary to **reproduce it in the question itself**_. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: Use mobile debugging in chrome https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.
I just put the following code to the element css, and it solves the problem. The weird layout was caused on iPhone btw.

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
```

Answer (score -1):

You have other rules that might be in effect at mobile sizes, search for `input.submit` inside your website files and see where it is located and modify it

Comment: No, there isn't. In my code I have a specific class for this input.submit (which I removed here).

Comment: maybe it is better to place the whole css and html code here to get help

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary. I already isolated the problem, and I keep getting the same result.